# isomorphic groups related in direct product.

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

I want to prove that the direct product $G\times H$ of two groups has a subgroup isomorphic to $G$ and a subgroup isomorphic to $H$.

How I thought to prove is that taking a pair $(g,h)$ from $G\times H$ and then to show that for some $g$ in $G$ there is an isomorphism with the pair $(g,h)$ of $G\times H$. and the same for $h$ in $H$ also. 
Is this method correct? Or should I try to show that there is a bijection between the groups and there exists an equivalence relation between the groups?

Please explain how should I proceed.

Comment: The subgroup isomorphic to $G$ is just $\{ (g,e) \in G \times H\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you think about these subgroups

$$K_1=\{(g,e): g\in G\}$$
$$K_2=\{(e,h): h\in H\}$$

rspectively isomorphic to $G$ and $H$?